# Generating Manually Scheduled Crystal Reports in C#

Tags: sql, database, crystal-reports, report, manual

I have a SQL Database from which I need to create reports daily, weekly and monthly. I am thinking of Creating Crystal Reports Manually so That I can execute that particular function periodically using a timer. Would this be a good approach or is there any other way in which I can do so?
An example would be greatly appreciated...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, you can use SQL Server Reporting Services.

Comment: You can do this with Crystal Reports. Are the reports already built or are you starting fresh?

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for Crystal Reports, but assuming you have SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services installed, you can create reports that way and not have to get a second software package.

Both Microsoft Technet (["How to: Schedule Report and Subscription Processing (Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283320%28v=sql.105%29)) and Code Snippets ("[SSRS: Scheduling Reports Using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008](http://snippetsandhelp.blogspot.com/2011/02/ssrs-scheduling-reports-using-sql.html)") have some examples of scheduling reports.